# Is there a way to rename a repository on Bitbucket using their API

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I couldn't find anything even remotely related in the documentation.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### For version 2.0 of the API:

According to https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/api-group-repositories/#api-repositories-workspace-repo-slug-put

```
PUT https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{repo_slug} --data "{\"name\": \"${new_name}\"}"
```

Using the PUT method allows renaming of a repository.

### For version 1.0 of the API:

According to https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/repository+Resource+1.0:

```
PUT https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/{accountname}/{repo_slug} --data "name=new name"
```

This allows to update the visible name of a repository.

Comment: Sadly, this does not work for the Server/Datacenter product.

Answer (score 65):

Using the Bitbucket website you can rename a repo as follows:

1. Go to the repo's overview page, usually `https://bitbucket.org/username/oldname/overview`
2. Click the settings cog on the far right end of the menu row !
3. Instead of 1. and 2. you can type `'r'` then `'a'` for administration.
4. Change the name in the `Name` field.
5. Click `Save repository details.`

Be advised that changing the name of the repo will change its URL access too. Previously the access was `https://username@bitbucket.org/username/oldname.git` Now, however, the repo's URL/Path will be `https://username@bitbucket.org/username/newname.git`

You can check this by going back to the Overview page, and hovering over the big blue HTTPS button. The bottom of your browser will show that it now points to `https://username@bitbucket.org/username/newname.git`

If you are using SourceTree you can update the remote's URL by highlighting the local repo in SourceTree and then

1. Click `Repository`
2. Click `Repository Settings...`
3. Highlight the row containing the remote branch. Usually `origin https://username@bitbucket.org/username/oldname.git`
4. Click `Edit`
5. Update the `URL/Path` field. Change 'oldname.git' to 'newname.git', leave the rest unchanged. So the full path should be `https://username@bitbucket.org/username/newname.git`
6. Click `OK`

Comment: If you cannot find the Settings button, currently it is "hidden" in the lower left corner.

Comment: The question is about the API, so although this answer contains useful info, it doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 4):

In a unix shell you can use cURL;

```
curl https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/{accountname}/{old_repo_name} --data "name=new_repo_name" -X PUT
```

Is it possible for a user to authenticate in private repositories, but still have only administrators able to execute:

```
curl https://USER:PASS@api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/{accountname}/{old_repo_name} --data "name=new_repo_name" -X PUT
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone hits this with looking for a solution to an old version of the bitbucket API (in my case 5.14.0) to say the documentation on this version is lacking is being quite polite.

```
curl --location --request PUT 'https://git.local.install/rest/api/1.0/projects/aa/repos/my-repo' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic .....' \ 
--data-raw '{"name":"my-new-name"}'
```

Comment: Damn. Thank you. Where is this documented? Is this info seen here https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/5.16.0/bitbucket-rest.html#idm8287362016 ?

Comment: Sorry i cant remember how i came upon this command, i think it was lots of trial and error

Answer (score 0):

According to the lastest API here is the correct curl command:

```
curl -X PUT --user username:password https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/repositories/{accountname}/{repo_slug}  --data "name=newRepoName"
```

Note that the repo_slug is the repository name IN LOWER CASE. If you don't put it all in lower case you would get the not so expressive answer "Not Found".

If you are not sure what is the repository slug execute the following command, which shows you the user's information including current repositories, and look for the field "slug"

```
curl --user username:password https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/user
```